# X11 error message unter shiny server but normal user works

Tags: r, shiny, x11

I'm getting an error when I run my shiny app. It says

```
Warning in pngfun(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, res = res,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
Warning: Error in .External2: unable to start device PNG
  127: pngfun
  126: startPNG
  125: drawPlot
  111: <reactive:plotObj>
   95: drawReactive
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$GB
    1: runApp
```

I searched already a lot of examples but somehow this is a little new.
I managed to get everything running as normal user and checked the `capabilities()`

```
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

However, when I `su - shiny` the capabilities change to

```
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

So `X11` looks unsupported for my shiny user and that might be the problem within the shiny server?
I have a debian linux system and I guess everything is installed, since it is working as a normal user. But not sure how to check and what could be missing.

### Edit

Found a link to a maybe solution but I am not able to set it up:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019922654-Working-with-packages-that-require-X11-and-or-cairo-on-RStudio-Server-Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how and why, but after loading the `Cairo` library within my shiny app, the problem is gone now.